# Should it be "could be" or "could have been" in the following?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

> The motel was so rusty and shabby that it could be/could have been
> mistaken for an abandoned house.

Should it be could be or could have been?

I'm not sure of the answer because I know that could (and must) don't have tense.

Note: This is past tense narration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct:

> The motel was so rusty and shabby that it **could have been** mistaken
> for an abandoned house.

Saying "could be" would sound wrong, because the first verb in the sentence ("was") is in a past tense. "Could be" is a present tense.